# How can I use reporting verbs

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference

My sentence from a grammar site is "At least 6 people are believed to have been killed in a shooting rampage". Will there be any difference if I turn it into:

1. There are believed to have been 6 people killed in a shooting rampage.
2. There are believed to be 6 people killed in a shooting rampage.

Are they even grammatically correct? If they are, do they mean the same or does perfect infinitive mean that those 6 people were killed in the past (then I can suggest my second example should be incorrect). As I understand we use the pronoun there to let people know that something exists, so the top sentence means we've already mentioned "people" and now we are talking about the dead ones, while my imaginary sentences mean we've only mentioned a shooting rampage, not people, so talking about people gives us new information (there are...)? However, my thoughts don't matter if the sentences I've made up are incorrect. I'd like to find out what they all should look like and why. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your *reason* for wanting to say the same thing using different words? Your two alternatives are both syntactically valid, but they're ***not*** what a native Anglophone would say *unless the writer wished to imply some unusual different nuance*. For example, the original more or less ***entails*** the fact that there was a shooting - it's just not certain how many people were killed. But both your versions give the impression there might feasibly not even have been a shooting at all.

Comment: ...I wouldn't call ***there are believed...*** a "reporting verb". It's a ***hedging*** construction (making an assertion, whilst simultaneously pointing out that the assertion might not be true).

Comment: @FumbleFingers , I don't have a personal reason for that but the site said "We can also use the same structure with the pronoun there" and I thought why not. They didn't explain the difference. Talking of the fact that there was a shooting, people can believe anything, it may not be true. But as far as I understand the sentence, they believe in the fact those people are dead, a shooting is just a place where those people are believed to have been killed, I can even leave out "in a shooting rampage" and I can't understand how it changes everything

Comment: @FumbleFingers , about hedging any assertion might not be true if it's not a fact but just something believed

Comment: In the original, what's "believed" is that the number of deaths is at least 6 (it's "implicit" that there really was a shooting). Unless your alternatives were changed to refer to ***the** shooting rampage*, they both more strongly imply that there might not even have been a shooting. These aren't exactly differences in meaning - just *likely intended nuance*. But we can't easily "explain" the meaning of your versions, because they wouldn't normally be used in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, thank you, the article makes sense. Now I understand it a little better. But still, why can the original sentence go without the? Nobody would just start telling you about 6 random dead people when you haven't heard of any accidents and don't understand what is going on. Is that something like the news? Can a reporter start their reporting about killed people without informing you of the shooting rampage caused death before it?

Comment: I'm repeating myself. The original version ***entails*** the fact that there ***was*** a shooting. And this is ***newspaper reporting*** style anyway. No normal person just walks up to someone else and starts talking like a newspaper or TV news reporter. You can't really learn "conversational" English from newspapers and such,  and you *definitely* shouldn't assume that what you see on their websites (or indeed on language teaching sites that use them for examples) accurately reflects how native Anglophones talk among themselves.

Comment: And what "grammar site" would that be? Please always provide sources.

Comment: You can of course make it more interesting by eliminating the expletive "there" and the passive "are" and "been":  "*An estimated 6 people died in a shooting rampage at … in …, this morning.*".